# Jquery Drag-and-Drop cloned image problems

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, resize, clone

I am working on a drag-and-drop project and need to drag the clone of a resizable image to a dropzone.  Once it has been dropped I want the clone to also be resizable and draggable. I don't want to create a clone of the clone...just be able to move it around.  My objective is to make each clone of the image independent of the original. My thinking is the I specify an id for the original and change the id on each clone as it is dropped.  I've researched and noticed that the general recommendation is that I wrap the image in a  tag and resize that using 'alsoResize' of the image.  My problem is that once I create the clone and drop it I can no longer resize it or drag it. Here is some code I'm working with...

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>draggable demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
    <style>  

        #draggable {    
            width: 100px;    
            height: 100px;    
            background: #ccc;  }  
        #drophere {
            width:600px;
            height:600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // set global id counter
      var gIDCnt = 0;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"> 

   <div id="draggable">Drag me</div> 
   <div id="img0" class="imgwrapper">
        <img class= "image" src="koala.jpg" style="height: 100px;" alt="Koala Bear" />
   </div> 
    <script>
     $(function(){

        $( "#draggable" ).resizable().draggable();

        $(".imgwrapper").resizable({
             aspectRatio: true,
             handles: 's,e,se',
             alsoResize: '.image'
        }).draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid",
            appendTo: "body"
        });

        $("body").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable, .imgwrapper, .onQuestion, .image",
        drop: function (event, ui) {        

            var isOnQuestion = $(ui.draggable).hasClass("onQuestion");
            if (isOnQuestion == true) {
                // Have already dropped this once, don't use clone anymore
                var element = $(ui.draggable);
            } else {
                var element = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            };

             // Set the absolute position of object
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
            var x = pos.left - offset.left;
            var y = pos.top - offset.top;
            $(element).css({ "left": x, "top": y, "position": "absolute" });

            if (isOnQuestion == false) {
                 //alert("Not on Question");
                 $(element).removeClass("imgwrapper");
                 //$(element).resizable("destroy");
                 //$(element).draggable("destroy");
                 gIDCnt= gIDCnt + 1;
                 var nextID = gIDCnt.toString();
                 var cNextID = "img"+nextID;

                 //alert(" ID: "+cNextID);
                 // Update with new ID
                 $(element).prop("id",cNextID);
                 var curid = $(element).attr("id");
                 $(element).addClass("onQuestion");
                 //alert("id: "+$(element).attr('id'));
                 $(element).children(".image").addClass("imageOn");

                 $(element).children(".image").removeClass("image");
                 //alert("id: "+$(element).attr('id'));
                 var cToResize = "#img"+nextID+" > .imageon";
                 //alert("cToResize: "+cToResize);
                 // Here's where I tried to make resizable
                 //$(element).resizable();
                 //$(element).resizable("option",{
                 // alsoResize: cToResize,
                 // aspectRatio: true,
                 // });
                 $('#'+cNextID).draggable();
                 $(element).css({border: "1px solid red"});

          }     
            $("body").append(element);
        }
       });
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I update the 'id' of each cloned image and then do a resize using the new id as the selector for a resize. However, if I try to destroy the resize and draggable functionality of the new cloned object and then try to resize,etc. then nothing works.  You'll notice in my code that I have several alerts commented out.  I add a class (onQuestion) to each cloned object so I can detect when it has been previously put in the dropzone so that I don't try to clone it again. I remove the original class (imgWrapper)  but when I try to execute...

```
        $(element).resizable("destroy");
        $(element).draggable("destroy");
```

none of the code that follows executes. I'm beginning to wonder if I need to research using event handlers with this.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: Create a JSFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) and post link here. So we can test and edit your code.

Comment: Here's link to JSFiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tpiwizard/r66x8/)  Thanks, Ken